# jquery: prevent click inside div from closing it ... all elements

Tags: jquery

Problem as in subject.

**Sample**:

```
<div id="trigger">click here</div>
<div id="slider"> content goes here: form elems, divs, spans, a etc. </div>
```

**How do I do it so far**:

```
    $(document.body).click(function(event){ 
        var target = $(event.target); 
          if (!target.is("#trigger") && !target.is("#slider") && [all elems in slider.div...]
}
```

**What I try to accomplish**:
Avoid listing all slider.div elems by id - if possible.

Allow one elem like div with id="close" inside of slider div to close it.

Comment: Do you want the button to disappear when the slider closes, or do you want the button to stay visible, so you can open and close the slider multiple times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished a number of ways, but my favorite is to name the trigger something like `slider_1` and give it a class if `.slider`. Then give the actual slider an id of `slider_1_content` with a class if `.slider_content`. This will allow you to write something like:

```
$(".slider").click(function() {
    $("#" + this.attr("id") + "_content") ...
});
```

You can then assign a `close` class to your close buttons/links and force them to close the parent slider like:

```
$(".close").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".slider_content").hide();
});
```

Comment: [ **`.closest()`** ](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) will, `"Get the first ancestor element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree."` OP's elements are **siblings** not descendants. ------ Also, if the parent is the slider, the button will disappear. You could use `.find()` for parent buttons and child sliders.

Comment: the `.close` button/link would be a descendant not a sibling. The first piece of code I posted address the trigger/slider issue.

Comment: Precisely. If the `close` classed DIV is a descendant, then if you click on it, it will **disappear** (along with the slider contents)!! If it's not a descendant, then `closer()` won't work. Try it out ==> http://jsfiddle.net/tSTcL/ ---- PS: I don't get notified you commented back unless you start your message with `@Peter`. Only authors and editors of a post get automatic notification.

Comment: As the OP describes it he wants a close button inside the slider that will close the slider when clicked. Since he wants the button to appear in the slider the button would logically be a descendant of the slider.

Comment: @Chris - The wording in the OP is somewhat unclear. I was inferring the meaning from the context and the title, `"prevent click inside div from closing it "` ------ Also, the sample HTML in the OP includes siblings..... But your guess is as good as mine ;)

Comment: @Peter - I think you read this wrong, Chris has exactly what the OP asked for, a close button inside closes it (what *else* would a close button possibly do?).

Comment: @Nick - Rereading the question, I think you and Chris are right. I'll probably delete my answer in a few days unless we hear back from Jeffz to the contrary.